# Nested IF condition not working in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This doesn't seems to be working in Google spreadsheet, can anyone help me out?

```
=IF(P70 <= 0, "NYS", IF(AND(P70 > 0, P70 <= 99), "WIP", IF(P70 >= 100, "COM")))
```

Comment: your innermost IF has no else statement

Answer (score 1):

IF statement require 3 arguments: IF(condition, true_exp, false_exp).
You forgot the false_exp in the innermost IF.
It could be expressed more clearly like:

```
=IF(P70 <= 0, "NYS", IF(P70 <= 99, "WIP", "COM"))
```

Comment: FYI: this appeared in the low quality posts review queue. Probably because it is a code only answer.